# How to handle continuous or quickly repeating actions with redux

Tags: redux

I am trying to reason about the best way to handle continuous, quickly repeating actions in Redux.

Say for example, I have a series of sliders representing `RGB` values and a component of my state is `Color` which is set via action by these sliders.

A user could be flying back and forth across a slider, if I trigger a new action for every change, then it's possible the slider could appear to stutter. For example, the user could be manipulating the `Red` slider. One action could be dispatched at a value of 0.5, and the user keeps sliding very quickly to 1.0. by the time the state update gets back the user is at 1.0 but the state update is for 0.5, followed soon after by the 1.0 event.

The result will be a slider knob that jumps back then jumps forward. For the sake of the question, lets just assume that's the case.

Anyway, I am curious how to prevent something like that. My first instinct would be to debounce the Action and let the view update it's representation accordingly. Then when the debounced action does eventually fire, it means the user has stopped, so when the new value of `Color` comes in from the state they will be equal and it will look like nothing has changed.

Is this the right way to handle something like this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, handling updates locally via component state and debouncing dispatch of a Redux action is an absolutely viable strategy.  I actually discussed this in my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 7: Form Change Handling, Data Editing, and Feature Reducers](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/), where I show off a reusable generic form input buffering component that can handle that for you.